# QGIS Shortcut to show/hide unselected layer

Tags: qgis

I'm working with a TIFF layer, two layers to be exact, Layer A and Layer B.

On layer A, I will be marking point of interest using vector point. But I will also need to quickly hide layer A and show Layer B to check reference on it.

Is there any shortcut to hide/show specific layer without selecting it?

Answer (score 6):

you can use "toggle selected layer indepentetly" see animation below:

[image]